# Rename the heartbeats topic in Mirror Maker 2.0 on the source cluster

Tags: apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to make use of KIP-690 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-690%3A+Add+additional+configuration+to+control+MirrorMaker+2+internal+topics+naming+convention and change the name of the heartbeats topic on the source cluster.  I have tried setting replication.policy.heartbeats.topic to be name I want but still get a topic called heartbeats on the source cluster.

My full configuration is:

```
source->destination.enabled = true
offset-syncs.topic.location = target
source->destination.topics = vault.core_api.v1.accounts.account.events
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor = 1
clusters = source,destination
config.storage.replication.factor = 1
config.storage.topic = vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.config
destination.bootstrap.servers = destination:29092
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor = 1
max.tasks = 4
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor = 1
offset.storage.replication.factor = 1
offset.storage.topic = vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.offset
replication.policy.heartbeats.topic = SOME_OTHER_NAME
source.bootstrap.servers = source:29092
source.group.id = external_kafka_connect.mm2
status.storage.replication.factor = 1
status.storage.topic = vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.status
sync.topic.configs.enabled = true
```

Basically I don't control the source cluster and don't have rights to create topics.  I've managed to rename most of the topics and ensure that the offset-syncs topic is created on the target cluster (which I do control).  The last topic I need to relocate/or use one of the names available to me is the heartbeats topic.

The full list of topics on the source cluster is:

```
__consumer_offsets
heartbeats
vault.core_api.v1.accounts.account.events
vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.config
vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.offset
vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.status
```

And the list of topics on the destination cluster is:

```
__consumer_offsets
heartbeats
mm2-offset-syncs.destination.internal
mm2-offset-syncs.source.internal
source.checkpoints.internal
source.vault.core_api.v1.accounts.account.events
vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.config
vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.offset
vault.infra.external.kafka_connect.default.status
```